# Getting blank array for Extension from x509 ParseCertificateRequest

Tags: go, decode, x509, pem, csr

I'm trying to get the challengePassword attribute from a CSR using Go. I've verified that the challengePassword attribute exists using `openssl req -in test.csr -noout -text`.

Below is the code snippet I'm using to print an array containing all attributes, omitting err checking. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
block, _ := pem.Decode(csrData)
csr, err := x509.ParseCertificateRequest(block.Bytes)

fmt.Println(csr.Extensions)
```

This simply returns `[]`. Where I would have expected to get an array containing extensions/attributes in the CSR and their associated values.

Comment: Go Play for reference example https://go.dev/play/p/e2QLvw0bT7X

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.